# MVC3: Best approach on where to store small images on webserver which can be uploaded and deleted by user.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have implemented upload/delete Logo functionality in my MVC3/C# WebApp. Where would be the correct folder to store these? I am currently using "Uploads/Logos" off root. Now of course the folder permissions prevent me from deleting files which got me thinking as to whether this is the correct place. Perhaps it should be in the "Content" or "App_Data" folder ??

Thoughts appreciated?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any difference between any folder you choose, provided that you set the permissions such that the application can delete the files.  If the current folder denies those permissions, change its permissions.

Comment: Can you create a Seperate Folder for images outside your Project? Then create a Virtual Directory inside your project for this new image folder? Could you create GUID names for your images ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are linking to the files directly, then you cannot place them in the `App_Data` folder as any request to an item in `App_Data` will be rejected.